# Can I register as huawei developer from one country with another country's mobile number?

Tags: registration, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

I want to register as a developer Huawei developer portal, But facing problem.

In my case, I am Yemeni, but I reside in the Kingdom of Saudi Arabia. When I enter my data, it asks me for a Yemeni phone number, and I do not have it at the moment. I have a Yemeni ID proof and a Saudi phone number, but the system did not accept to change the country.

How can I register, please anyone help on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **country/region** in your identity information is set to the one you have chosen during account registration and **cannot be changed**. If you want to use another country/region, you are advised to register a new account.

You can login with different phone number but at the time of verification you have to give the data of that country/region which you have mentioned. You cannot change the Country code in verification page, you have to give the phone number of country/region which you have mentioned at the time of registration. You may set **different phone number for login purpose only**.

**Please note you have to give same Country/region phone number for Verification information. Neither country code nor Country/region can be changed in Verification information page.**

Please refer Screenshot for more clarity.

[image: Registration page]
[image: Pop up message]
[image: Verification page]
[image: Account center]
[image: Change phone number]

Thank you.